# small sense of joy/novelty from shared (http) links

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I know I saw a word a few years ago used to describe *the small sense of joy/novelty/excitement we exchange when we send/receive cool links with others*. Now, I can't recall the word, or where I saw it.

I am not sure whether it was a repurposed word, or a neologism.

I have a feeling it may be related to [frisson](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/frisson), but this feeling hasn't helped me find the word I'm looking for, despite searching several times over the past two years (and as such may be a red herring).

**Edit**: I've found a few places where others are expressing some of the underlying emotional makeup of this, but still not the word; figured I would *share* with you.

from [Yahoo questions](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080929104144AASFP8k):

> Where can i find funny links to cheer up my friend?
> My friend is having a bad day and i´d like to send some funny links to make her laugh. What u suggest?

from [HuffPo: Tech ettiquete - sharing links](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/01/13/tech-etiquette-sharing-links_n_1205703.html):

> You are not the person who watches the watchmen! You can only lead a horse to water. You cannot make a horse open a link or, for that matter, react to it in the way you want. Yes, sharing something you feel all crazy about is a wonderful, personal experience. Yes, you are excited and want to see the recipient's reaction in the hopes that it will be like your reaction. Refrain.
>
> ...
>
> There are not enough links in this world to constitute a romantic relationship. Sending links is just something people do now, like day dreaming about cool Facebook albums or looking at their phone all the time. Usually, the fact that you have received this link is only tangentially related to you. There are three reasons people like to show other people things they like:
>
> A) To get validation that the things they like are cool.
> B) So that the receiver will know they are cool.
> C) Because they think the link will bring the receiver pleasure.
>
> Ideally, this list would be inverted, but in reality it is not. The sending of the link should be it's own reward. If it isn't, see #1.

from [makeuseof](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/top-10-disgusting-websites-to-share-with-friends/):

> Are you constantly looking for something fresh and interesting to link to from your MySpace or Facebook account to intrigue and fascinate your friends?
>
> ...
>
> There is one remaining, very powerful way to provoke a reaction from your half-asleep friends. Link to one of the following top 10 disgusting websites, and watch what sort of response you get.

from [WikiHow: get your crush to be your friend](http://www.wikihow.com/Get-Your-Crush-to-Be-Your-Friend):

> If you both have a Facebook account, share similar links to those of your crush's, based on what you see from him/her, or on his/her profile. He or she may 'like' or even comment on the links you post! Just never share the exact same links.

Comment: Are you thinking of serendipity?  Its more general though - the joy of an unanticipated find

Comment: Seremdipity is more about fortunate unexpected circumstances. This is more a sense of joy from sharing a thing which both parties would enjoy, and doesn't carry the unexpected or circumstantial quality of serendipity. As a general world, I'd suggest something more akin to "elation".

Comment: I seriously doubt there's a dedicated term for the *exact* context you describe. Does it have to be Internet-based exchanges, or could a letter through the post have the same effect? Does the specific information sent/received have to be a "link", or could it be actual text/artwork? Does it really have to be the ***same*** "small sense of joy/etc." for both sender and receiver?

Comment: I remember seeing this word somewhere as well. I think it's in same category as [“sonder”](http://niel.delarouviere.com/2013/06/curious-case-word-sonder/).

Comment: @AffableGeek Not serendipity.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The specifics are a little distant to me now; the term may have merely indicated the experience of the recipient. The term was repurposed/neologized to describe a largely online phenomena. 

We don't generally send our friends 20 real artifacts a day, and I suspect the joy/novelty/excitement they experienced would be more significant (at receiving an object) than the small/passing sensation in response to what we find at the other end of a link.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung I suspect it is similar to the thoughtful words neologized in the [DoOS](http://www.dictionaryofobscuresorrows.com/), aside from not describing a sorrow.

Comment: @abathur: Are you perhaps thinking of [Easter eggs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)) in the "computing/internet" sense?

Comment: So are you asking for the feeling of joy in the intimacy of having someone to share things with or the joy and surprise of opening something someone sent you?  I perceive those feelings to be slightly different.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I agree that they are different. I suspect it was the emotion of the receiver--but having gone a few years without seeing the word (or its definition) it is hard for me to state certainly that the word didn't describe the sender's emotion, or more broadly the *exchange* in which the receiver is experiencing a small joy and the sender is experiencing a small validation from the receiver's joy.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, though a page about an easter egg, or a video of someone finding an easter egg, could easily be one of the sorts of links exchanged.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt if this was it but would you consider the wonderful word ***twitterpated***?

*twitter* - twittering or tremulous excitement; 
*twitterpated* - thrilled, excited

Although the [origins](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/twitterpated) predate Twitter by a mile, the term has taken semantic drifts  and will be understood in a modern interpretation by most people if context is made clear.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably describe this as ***amusement***, which I tend to think of as rather small and fleeting compared to other words in the same vein.

Answer (score 1):

This is a W.A.G. chosen from a list of synonyms for "surprise" that start with an "F":

> **fil·lip**
>
> transitive verb \ˈfi-ləp\
>
> 3:  stimulate - "...with this to fillip his spirits" — Robert Westerby
>
> And here are the synonyms for **"fillip"**:
>
> amp (up), brace, energize, enliven, animate, fire, ginger (up),
> invigorate, jazz (up), juice up, jump-start, liven (up), pep (up),
> quicken, spike, stimulate, vitalize, vivify, zip (up)

Comment: In BrEng W.A.G stands for wives and girlfriends, and I just can't work out its meaning in your answer.

Comment: Found it, wild assed guess. I like it!

Comment: @Mari-LouA, that's it! Lol! :-)

Comment: You are BUWT - fillip refers to a stimulus, not the experience.

Comment: @user49727, IYO. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[***a boot***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/boot) slang; a swift, pleasurable feeling; a thrill

> *Watching that young skater win a gold medal gave me a real boot*. (Dictionary.com)

What moment could be swifter than a *boot*? Its meaning similar to *kick*; it might be used to describe that moment when one opens a file or link that has been sent by friends.

> That was a real boot

Otherwise, ***a hoot*** which expresses a fleeting moment of fun or hilarity

> it's an old joke but a real hoot

Answer (score -2):

Is it "**empathy**" (no direct connection with "sympathy") which the fact of mentally identifying your feelings with somebody else (it could be joy, sadness, etc.), almost as from inside.

Comment: -1 "Empathy" is sharing *someone else's* feelings. I understand the question as referring to *your own* feelings when exchanging/sending/receiving links with others.